# React.js HATEOAS client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hateoas

If I do the following http call to my api on resource /people and return

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "people": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/person/1"
          },
          "person": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/person/1"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/person"
    }
  }
}
```

The data is being rendered on screen in a table and currently I expose my id's from my backend and use the following link for my `react-router` to handle

```
<Link to={`person/${this.props.person.id}`}>Detail</Link>
```

Here I can't pass the link in the rendered link and have to pass the id to do the detail call in my backend. But instead of constructing the `href` manually I want to use the url at `_links.self.href` in my next component.

How can I achieve this without exposing id's in my React application?

Comment: `I can't pass it as a parameter since it's a link` Can you expand on that a little? Also, how are you routing? react-router?

Comment: You were right it was unclear, is it better now?

Comment: Much clearer, thanks. But won't `<Link to={`${this.props.person._links.self.href}`}>Detail</Link>` do what you want? I'm assuming `person` is the structure from that array in your API response.

Comment: No, the json is returned from my api and the value in the `href` is the location at my backend.

Answer (score 1):

Found a question with the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169068/passing-state-via-this-history-pushstate).

In the Link use:

```
<Link to={{pathname: "/person", state: { person: person }}} />
```

And in the referenced component:

```
this.props.location.state.person
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is almost identical to the example I give in my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18083285/760706

The main issue I would take with what you have presented is that the resource you have included in the `_embedded` section (`/person/1`) is not included in the links of the collection resource, the main `_links` section. Instead you have listed it next to `self` within the person's own links.

The second problem I see is that the link relation you have used, "people" (which actually links to an individual person), is not a URI nor on the IANA registered link relations list. These are the only two legal types of link relation. In this instance, your collection should use the registered relation `item` to point to its members. For custom relations, your URI should be a HTTP URL under a domain you control, pointing to documentation, so that users can look up the documentation for that link relation by going to the URL.